# How to bypass system /signature level for a modified system apk?

Tags: applications, root-access, system-apps

I made a modification on a system app but it should be signed with the same certificate as the Firmware to work properly, is there any workaround to bypass this ?

Answer (score 0):

As far I know you need a custom firmware to do it (I guess you don't have access to the firmware keys to resign your apk) so:

- a) You can modify,  compile and install your custom Android that skips the signing verification in apps that request to use the android.uid.system user or
- b) You can install a custom ROM signed with AOSP keys (most of the custom ROMs are signed using the testkeys from AOSP) and sign you app using the same key in order to get the system level (you can use  keytool-importkeypair tool to create a keystore and used it on Android Studio or gradle

Answer (score 0):

Hm.. I have CyanogenMod 12.1 and I just extract META-INF from original apk and add it in my custom system apk. All works properly

Comment: Interesting approach - if this isn't just a CyanogenMod bug this would mean the signature of a system app is never checked as it is never installed via package manager (who is usually performing the signature check).

Comment: Can you do this when not rooted?